# Method Delete not allowed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, api, web

Im doing a delete method when i click the button but it says

```
DELETE http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/DeleteEmployeeDetail/16 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

my code for the button is

```
deleteEmployee(id) {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
  fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/DeleteEmployeeDetail/'+ id, {
       method: 'DELETE'
}).then(function(response) {

}).catch(function(err) {
  // Error :(
});

}
```

ive already change a lot on my web config i dont know which is which that has an error

for my web config

```
       <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:8080" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <modules  runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
     <remove name="WebDAVModule" />    
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />   
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />
         <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <remove name="Babel" />
      <add name="Babel" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" path="*.jsx" type="React.Web.BabelHandlerFactory, React.Web" preCondition="integratedMode" /><remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" /><remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" /><remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" /><add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" /></handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
```

Comment: By default ASP.NET does not handle `DELETE`, `PUT`, and `PATCH` verbs because the WebDAV handler intercepts them. Please post your web.config so we can see how you've customized your `<httpHandlers>` collection.

Comment: hey Ive changed my question and put my web config i dont know whats wrong tho @Dai

Comment: why you add ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 handler and after remove it?

Comment: hey it works! i just need to change the method delete to get lol it took me forever! lol